# How to count/ find specific listview items (class)?

Tags: c#, class, listview, windows-store-apps

I have a listView filled with Classes (PlayCard).
I want to count the classes with the same values for `cardNumber`
If the number is more than twice in the listView I want testBool to become true

I got this code already:

```
foreach (PlayCard pCard in listView1.Items)
{               
    if (listView1.Items.Count(i => i.cardNumber == pCard.cardNumber) > 1)
    {
        pCard.testBool = true;
    }
}
```

but i got a error:

> 'Object' does not contain a definition for 'cardNumber' and no
>   extension method 'cardNumber' accepting a first argument of type
>   'object' could be found.

```
class PlayCard
{
        public int cardNumber { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public bool testBool = false;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your listView1 is a list of objects, and the Object class doesn't have a cardNumber method.  If you know that the objects are in fact `PlayCard` objects, then a cast should fix the problem, i.e.

```
foreach (PlayCard pCard in listView1.Items)
{ 

    if (listView1.Items.Count(i => ((PlayCard)i).cardNumber == pCard.cardNumber) > 1) 
    // etc
```

Comment: Realy thanks, it works. i know it had something to do with the object thing but didnt get the syntax right.

Answer (score 1):

The ListView Control just contains items of type `object`.

Use this `if`-statement:

```
if (listView1.Items.Count(i => ((PlayCard)i).cardNumber == pCard.cardNumber) > 1)
```

It should work now!

Comment: Realy thanks, it works. i know it had something to do with the object thing but didnt get the syntax right